# Using axios POST Request to Update JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm very new to React and currently trying to figure out how to update a JSON file using a axios.post request. I have a feature where a user can upload a photo, and the goal is to add that photo's ID and imgURL to photos.json, where I'm storing that data.
Here's my post function:

```
            axios.post('/api/photos', image)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
```

I had post route to the create function in my photos controller, which looks like this:

```
    module.exports.create = (req, res) => {

        const photo = new Photo({
            id: req.body.id,
            imgURL: req.body.imgURL
        })
        photo.save()
            .then((resp) => {
                send_code_success(res,201, "photo save success");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                send_code_error(res,500, "photo save error");
                console.error("Could not save photo to database:", err);
            })     
    };
```

This is where I'm guessing the issue is, because honestly I'm not really sure what code should go here. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: How you update a file depends on the server-side API and has nothing to do with the client-side framework. What `Photo` is and thus why `save()` doesn't change the file is a completely mystery as you haven't provided enough detail about that.

Comment: in your create function, you need to return your saved document as JSON back to your front end, so your front end can consume it

Comment: Is the save() function who makes the post request? if yes you should pass photo as parameter `save(photo)` instead of `photo.save()`

Comment: @MahdiN photo.save() is correct, it use mongoose schema to save the photo

Answer (score 1):

in your create function, you need to return your saved document as JSON back to your front end, so your front end can consume it

```js
axios.post('/api/photos', image)
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
      //=>consume your JSON response
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})



module.exports.create = (req, res) => {

    const photo = new Photo({
        id: req.body.id,
        imgURL: req.body.imgURL
    })
    photo.save()
        .then((resp) => {
            //send_code_success(res,201, "photo save success");
            return res.status(200).json(resp) //=> return your saved doc to front end
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            send_code_error(res,500, "photo save error");
            console.error("Could not save photo to database:", err);
        })     
};
```